# How do I map complex objects with Automapper?

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I am trying to map 2 complex object in CustomDtoMapper and unable to do it because the second mapping, does not seem to work.

Second Mapping to EntityLine from DtoInputEntity results in null values. none of the values get assigned.

Here is my CustomDtoMapper class:

```
internal static class CustomDtoMapper
{
    private static volatile bool _mappedBefore;

    private static readonly object SyncObj = new object();

    public static void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression mapper)
    {
        lock (SyncObj)
        {
            if (_mappedBefore)
            {
                 return;
            }

            CreateMappingsInternal(mapper); 

            _mappedBefore = true;
        }
    }


    private static void CreateMappingsInternal(IMapperConfigurationExpression mapper)
    {
        mapper.CreateMap<User, UserEditDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Password, options => options.Ignore())
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(user => user.Password, options => options.Ignore());

        mapper.CreateMap<DtoInputEntity, Entity>()
            .ForMember(entityCreateDto => entityCreateDto.OrderNumber,
            dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.MapFrom(input => input.Response.OrderNumber))
            .ForMember(entityCreateDto => entityCreateDto.ShipmentNumber,
            dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.MapFrom(input => input.Response.ShipmentNumber));

        mapper.CreateMap<DtoInputEntity, EntityLine>()
            .ForPath(entityLineCreateDto => entityLineCreateDto.ExternalModelIdentifier, opt => opt.MapFrom(dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.Response.UTModelIdentifier))
            .ForPath(entityLineCreateDto => entityLineCreateDto.SKU, opt => opt.MapFrom(dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.Response.ModelIdentifier))
            .ForPath(entityLineCreateDto => entityLineCreateDto.ShipmentNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.Response.ShipmentNumber))
            .ForPath(entityLineCreateDto => entityLineCreateDto.LineNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(dtoInputEntity => dtoInputEntity.Response.LineNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the title of your question so that it's not SHOUTING. All caps is considered to be shouting. I didn't have a good idea for what your title should actually be, so please edit it appropriately (without SHOUTING). I have also indented your code to more closely follow standard C# conventions. Please do this yourself in the future before posting, as it improves readability and makes it more likely for someone to answer your question.

Comment: @mason : Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a dummy application to test your problem, and I can't seem to replicate it. As such, I suspect you might have a problem with your mapper instance(s) management, and not your initialization. You may be using an instance that differs from the one you initialize (considering your initializer is static, and only does it once), for example.

As a side note, why use ForPath, as opposed to ForMember?

I can't comment, otherwise, I would, instead of writing up an answer.

Comment: I am using ForPath because ForMemeber does not work for 2 layer objects. This is how I create my instances:   Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(mapper =>
            {
                CustomDtoMapper.CreateMappings(mapper);
            });

Comment: That is indeed true, but only applies to the output object, from my undestanding. I actually tested your example with both ForMember and ForPath, for curiosity sake, and they both work, as of version 6.2.2.0. 

I suggest you remove the _mappedBefore check, so you can test whether the problem lies in only initializing one instance. As a final note, I apologize for I am not familiar with the ASP.Net Boilerplate library, and as such, cannot help you further than this.